# Error: identifier '_Float128' is undefined with Intel Compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

we are currently compiling some software for our new cluster. However, for some of those, we run into the following issue, e.g. with [DIRAC 23.0](https://www.diracprogram.org/doku.php?id=start).

Our setup consists of intel compilers 2021.2.0 (various versions up to the current compilers 2024.0 were tested with unchanged outcomes), openmpi v5.0.1 (int64) and hdf5 v1.14.3.

Our PATH (formatted for better overview):

```
PATH=/home/mctc/software/hdf5/1.14.3/bin:
  /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin:
  /home/mctc/software/intel/oneapi-2021.2/vtune/2021.2.0/bin64:
  /home/mctc/software/intel/oneapi-2021.2/mpi/2021.2.0/libfabric/bin:
  /home/mctc/software/intel/oneapi-2021.2/mpi/2021.2.0/bin:
  /home/mctc/software/intel/oneapi-2021.2/debugger/10.1.1/gdb/intel64/bin:
  /home/mctc/software/intel/oneapi-2021.2/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin/intel64:
  /home/mctc/software/intel/oneapi-2021.2/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/bin:
  /home/mctc/software/intel/oneapi-2021.2/compiler/2021.2.0/linux/ioc/bin:
  /home/mctc/software/intel/oneapi-2021.2/advisor/2021.2.0/bin64:/usr/bin
```

We are setting up the build with the following arguments (formatted):

```
./setup --mpi --fc=mpif90 --cc=mpicc --cxx=mpicxx --mkl=parallel 
  --int64 --pcmsolver=off --exatensor=on --prefix=/home/mctc/software/dirac/23.0
```

The resulting configuration looks good to us:

```
-- The Fortran compiler identification is Intel 2021.2.0.20210228
-- The C compiler identification is Intel 2021.2.0.20210228
-- The CXX compiler identification is Intel 2021.2.0.20210228
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpif90 - skipped
-- Checking whether /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpif90 supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpif90 supports Fortran 90 - yes
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpicc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpicxx - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.6 (found version "3.6.15") 
-- User set explicit MKL flag which is passed to the compiler and linker: -mkl=parallel
-- This disables math detection and builtin math libraries
-- Setting -DHAVE_MKL_BLAS and -DHAVE_MKL_LAPACK
-- MATH_LIB_SEARCH_ORDER set to MKL;ESSL;OPENBLAS;ATLAS;ACML;SYSTEM_NATIVE
-- Found MPI_C: /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpicc (found version "3.1") 
-- Found MPI_CXX: /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpicxx (found version "3.1") 
-- Found MPI_Fortran: /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpif90 (found version "3.1") 
-- Found MPI: TRUE (found version "3.1")  
-- Found OpenMP_C: -qopenmp (found version "5.0") 
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES) 
-- Found OpenMP_Fortran: -qopenmp (found version "5.0") 
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FOUND) (found version "5.0")
-- Enable profiling: False
-- Enable run-time checking: False
-- Configure-time Linked math libs integer compatibility test ENABLED
-- Performing compile and run test of blas integer size (can deactivate with -D ENABLE_MATH_INT_TEST=OFF) 
-- Performing Test blas_test_compiled ...
-- Performing Test blas_test_compiled - Success
-- Performing Test blas_test_run
-- Performing Test blas_test_run - Failed
-- Test of blas integer size SUCCESS .. blas is integer*8 
-- We have BLAS-integer*8
-- Found HDF5: /home/friede/software/HDF5/1.14.3/lib64/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib64/libz.so;/usr/lib64/libdl.so;/usr/lib64/libm.so (found version "1.14.3") found components: C 
-- HFD5 found, enabling HDF5 interface 
-- HDF5 include directory location: /home/friede/software/HDF5/1.14.3/include 
-- MPI package type: INTEL
-- Compiling /home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/cmake/custom/test-MPI-compiler-compatibility.F90 ...
-- Performing Test MPI_COMPILER_MATCHES ...
-- Performing Test MPI_COMPILER_MATCHES - Success
-- mpi.mod matches the current MPI compiler, employing 'use mpi' and setting -DUSE_MPI_MOD_F90
-- Compiling /home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/cmake/custom/test-MPI-itype-compatibility.F90 ...
-- Performing Test MPI_ITYPE_MATCHES ...
-- Performing Test MPI_ITYPE_MATCHES - Success
-- Well, program got compiled with 64-bit integers, but the internal MPI integer compatibility test will be performed inside dirac.x.
-- Set CDash default timeout for single test set to 1500 seconds. Overwritten by test's TIMEOUT property label and, ultimatively, by pam timeout setting.
-- Test's 'basis_input_scripted' timeout set to 3600 seconds. Can be overwritten by pam's timeout setting.
-- -mkl=... flag for MKL libraries kept because Intel Fortran compiler is present
-- Polarizable Continuum Model via PCMSolver DISABLED
-- ExaTensor library can not work with 64 bit integers, switched off
-- Enable ExaTENSOR library: OFF
-- Gen1Int module: ON
-- PElib module: ON
-- The XCFun submodule ENABLED
-- ESR property module: ON
-- src/reladc/polprp_cousat.F: assigned -O2 optimization flag to fix the compilation with Intel
-- Stieltjes external module ENABLED
-- KRCC module: ON
-- Enable compilation of standalone relccsd.x: OFF
-- OpenRSP library: OFF
-- LAO properties without connection matrices: ON
-- Spinfree MCSCF module: ON
-- NOTE: tests for the (e)amfX2C 2e-scalar and spin-orbit picture-change correction module require h5py in your python env!
-- (e)amfX2C 2e-scalar and spin-orbit picture-change correction module: ON
-- srDFT module: ON
-- Specialized tutorial tests DISABLED
-- Unit control tests DISABLED
-- User name: wittmann
-- Host name: fs7
-- Operating system: Linux-5.14.21-150500.55.36-default
-- CMake version: 3.20.4
-- CMake generator: Unix Makefiles
-- CMake build type: release
-- Configuration time: 2024-01-24 07:58:03.880168
-- Fortran compiler ID: Intel
-- Fortran compiler: /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpif90
-- Fortran compiler version: Intel 2021.2
-- Fortran compiler flags:  -w -assume byterecl -g -traceback -DVAR_IFORT  -i8
-- C compiler ID: Intel
-- C compiler: /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpicc
-- C compiler version: Intel 2021.2
-- C compiler flags:  -g -wd981 -wd279 -wd383 -wd1572 -wd177 
-- CXX compiler ID: Intel
-- CXX compiler: /home/mctc/software/openmpi/5.0.1-int64/bin/mpicxx
-- CXX compiler version: Intel 2021.2.0
-- CXX compiler flags:  -Wno-unknown-pragmas 
-- Static linking: False
-- 64-bit integers: True
-- MPI parallelization: True
-- MPI launcher: /home/mctc/software/intel/oneapi-2021.2/mpi/2021.2.0/bin/mpiexec
-- Intel MKL flag: parallel
-- Compile definitions: HAVE_MKL_BLAS;HAVE_MKL_LAPACK;HAVE_MPI;VAR_MPI;VAR_MPI2;USE_MPI_MOD_F90;SYS_LINUX;PRG_DIRAC;INT_STAR8;INSTALL_WRKMEM=64000000;BUILD_GEN1INT;HAS_PELIB;HAS_STIELTJES;MOD_LAO_REARRANGED;MOD_MCSCF_spinfree;MOD_XAMFI;MOD_ESR;MOD_KRCC;MOD_SRDFT
-- Exacorr module enabled : OFF
-- Found HDF5: /home/friede/software/HDF5/1.14.3/lib64/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib64/libz.so;/usr/lib64/libdl.so;/usr/lib64/libm.so (found version "1.14.3") found components: C HL 
-- For checking, linked libraries to dirac.x: objlib.dirac.x;pelib_interface;/home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/build/external/lib/libstieltjes.a;xcfun_fortran_bindings;/home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/build/external/xcfun-build/src/libxcfun.a;/home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/build/external/lib/libpelib.a;gen1int_interface;/home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/build/external/lib/libgen1int.a;qcorr;HDF5::HDF5;laplace 
-- Found Sphinx: /usr/bin/sphinx-build  
-- Copied DIRAC basis set directories into the build directory
-- Copied data schema and python utilities into the build directory
-- Set CDash default timeout for single test set to 1500 seconds. Overwritten by test's TIMEOUT property label and, ultimatively, by pam timeout setting.
-- Test's 'basis_input_scripted' timeout set to 3600 seconds. Can be overwritten by pam's timeout setting.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/build
```

However, make will return the following issue (first three errors and a further one):

```
    ............
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/cstdlib(79),
                     from /home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/src/xcfun/src/xcfun.cpp(1):
    /usr/include/stdlib.h(152): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
      extern _Float128 strtof128 (const char *__restrict __nptr,
             ^
    
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/cstdlib(79),
                     from /home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/src/xcfun/src/xcfun.cpp(1):
    /usr/include/stdlib.h(245): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
                _Float128 __f)
                ^
    
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/cstdlib(79),
                     from /home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/src/xcfun/src/xcfun.cpp(1):
    /usr/include/stdlib.h(330): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
      extern _Float128 strtof128_l (const char *__restrict __nptr,
             ^
    ............

    ............
    In file included from /usr/include/math.h(423),
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/cmath(47),
                 from /home/mctc/source/dirac/23.0/src/xcfun/src/xcfun.cpp(4):
    /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h(73): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
    __MATHCALL (sinh,, (_Mdouble_ __x));

    ............
```

The full log can be found [here as a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3ycJB7Vk).

We already tried the approach described in [ICC 17.0.4 + GCC 7 + glibc 2.26: error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/ICC-17-0-4-GCC-7-glibc-2-26-error-identifier-quot-Float128-quot/td-p/1170601), however, the outcome was unchanged.

Now, we are unsure how to resolve this issue. It seems to be an issue with our (compiler) setup, as other software shows the same issue.

We have the suspicion, that in the bottom example above, the inclusion of GCC headers might be an issue, however we are clueless as to why GCC headers are used in the first place.

1. Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Intel compilers and '_Float128' recently?
2. Are there specific compiler flags or settings that need adjustment
   to resolve this error?
3. Any suggestions on resolving '_Float128' undefined errors with Intel compilers?

Comment: Note that `_Float128` is a relatively new addition from C23. If you were using new headers that use it with an older compiler that has no support, this could happen.